# css align table row differently without using another table

Tags: html, css

Are there any ways to not align the table cells?
I want my header to be between the table having something like

```
-------------
| | A | B | |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
```

Anyway to do this without using two table or using div instead of table?

I've tried something on the fiddle, but it's not working, the first table is what I want it to look like, but without using two tables
http://jsfiddle.net/nA3DL/

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Will colspan really solve it? I think not.

Comment: colspan should solve it, but meaning I have to give every cell a col span, the problem is that I have alot of tables that's already made, so I don't want to bother with those... best to just use css, but not sure if it can be done

Comment: I would not use tables at all, but you explicitly said you wanted to use tables, and colspan is the only way in which you will be able to do this in tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position relative on the headers, and move them to the left:

```
table.test th{
    width:100px;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
}
table.test th.half{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nA3DL/1/)

Comment: wow thanks alot! this actually worked! crap... if it was a little earlier... now i've changed half way through... but still thanks alot for this!

Comment: Happy that it helped. Will try to be faster next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use unsorted lists, but I'm not sure how much data you're going to show in your table.. Could be a lot of work, but if it's only your table-header that are going to have a different look this might be the way to do it:

CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 500px;
}

.table ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.table ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.table ul li.small {
    width: 50px;
}

.table ul li.big {
     width: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <ul>
        <li class="small"></li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li class="small"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="big">Data</li>
        <li class="big">Data</li>
        <li class="big">Data</li>
        <li class="big">Data</li>
        <li class="big">Data</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3dpnX/2/

Comment: thanks for sharing this, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but from the sound of it, I might not have any choices at all... either colspan or this, looks like a single table can't do it

Comment: You could add col-span with CSS, in that case you don't have to write col-span on every td.. If that's what you're trying to avoid. If you're afraid it might affect all your other tables, you could give this spesific table a class, and only this table will be affected

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, the column-span attribute in CSS does a whole other thing than colspan in html :/

Comment: ah! you've got my hopes up! haha